# Dynamic filter in spree

Tags: ruby-on-rails, dynamic, filter, spree

I use `spree(v. 0.70.5)` an I need realize dinamic filters for product. Options for the filter defined by the current taxon.

What should I do?

Comment: I'd start here: http://guides.spreecommerce.com/legacy/0-70-x/scopes_and_groups.html

Comment: Thanks. But this is not exactly what I need.

Comment: You'll generally get the amount of help commensurate with how much effort your question looks like you've put into it.  You've set the bar pretty low with this question, as it doesn't show you've put any work into at all.

Please see how to ask a question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-ask